# How to use flex to get this special distribution?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

My goal is to place 5 boxes on the corner and in the center.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPbvT.png)

These are my codes:

```css
.container {
      width: 240px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-content: space-between;
    }

    .container > div {
      width: 80px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one">  1</div>
    <div id="two">  2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four"> 4</div>
    <div id="five"> 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I change the code so that the fifth block is in the center and the others are orderly on the corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .container {
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}

.container > div {
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#five {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one">  1</div>
    <div id="two">  2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four"> 4</div>
    <div id="five"> 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

- Add `position: relative;` to the container so that div#5 is placed relative to it.

`left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` is a classic method to center a div.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `flex`, you might set `order` property of the flex-items:

```css
.container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.container>div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#one,
#two {
  order: 1;
}

#three,
#four {
  order: 3
}

#five {
  order: 2;
  margin: 0 78px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="one"> 1</div>
  <div id="two"> 2</div>
  <div id="three">3</div>
  <div id="four"> 4</div>
  <div id="five"> 5</div>
</div>
```